# Trigger android Battery charging Broadcast event

Tags: android, broadcast, battery

My phone has a strange problem: the touchscreen doesn't work when unplugged from the charger.
I want to try to fool Android by sending a broadcast (or whatever) that will make the system think it's charging so that my touchscreen starts working.

Should I send a broadcast event `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` via code? or something else?

I have root, so I don't mind an implementation that involves `su`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a hardware problem. While you can't send system broadcasts from your own processes, even if you could, I doubt it would fix your touchscreen.

Comment: it could be, but there shud be a way to send system broadcasts on rooted phones

Answer (score 0):

As 323go has suggested , you might have a hardware problem. So broadcasting an intent might not help.Anyway If you have a rooted phone,  On adb shell give below command

```
            am broadcast -a android.intent.action.YOURINTENT
```

Comment: That broadcast doesn't work on my ROOTed device. I get Broadcast completed: result=0

Comment: Result 0 is correct but did you change it to the appropriate intent. It was just an example

Comment: am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED am broadcast -a android.intent.action.REBOOT

Comment: Did you execute su before executing it